# Rending html in UIWebView and load images from cache

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

when user run my app for the first time i have loaded all the images and save it to my cache folder which is in Library directory: **Library/Caches/imgcache/myApp/ready/**

**Let say file with name :** 
http/__wscdn.bbc.co.uk_worldservice_assets_images_2012_01_13_120113094952_international_space_station_304x171_reuters_nocredit.jpg

Now when user is out of network i am rendering html using loadHTMLString, If html Contain any img src of previous stored file , it load from cache not from internet as user do not have access to internet .

**Now my question is how can i handle this issue ? How can i do this ? Please help me out ..**

For Example :

I have string with html in it ,

```
>"<div class="g-container story-body"> <div class="bodytext"> <div class="module "> <div >class="image img-w304"><img width="304" height="171" >src="http://wscdn.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/assets/images/2012/05/18/120518135959_facebook_304>x171_bbc_nocredit.jpg" alt=""/> <div class="module "> <div class="image img-w304"><img >width="304" height="171" >src="http://wscdn.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/assets/images/2012/05/18/120518145635_facebook_304>x171_bbc_nocredit.jpg" alt=""/><p class="caption"></p> </div> </div> <p></p> </div> </div> ><div class="g-container story-body"></div>"
```

**i have cached these two images in user document folder , 
now when user have no access to net i want to do something like this :**

```
><div class="g-container story-body"> <div class="bodytext"> <div class="module "> <div >class="image img-w304"><img width="304" height="171" >src="**Library/Caches/imgcache/myApp/ready/**http://wscdn.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/assets/ima>ges/2012/05/18/120518135959_facebook_304x171_bbc_nocredit.jpg" alt=""/> <div class="module >"> <div class="image img-w304"><img width="304" height="171" >src="**Library/Caches/imgcache/myApp/ready/**http://wscdn.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/assets/ima>ges/2012/05/18/120518145635_facebook_304x171_bbc_nocredit.jpg" alt=""/><p class="caption">>>``</p> </div> </div> <p></p> </div> </div> <div class="g-container story-body"></div>
```

Comment: Are you describing what you already have implemented or what you're trying to implement? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i have implemented the complete application , but what i want is when loading the html in UIwebview i would like to load images from cache folder not from net ..

Comment: Will this help http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the image cache through the webview's `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)stringbaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL` method. You need to specify the baseURL to your local app Library directory. Sample code below:

```
NSString * htmlContent = @"your html content";
NSString * path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"];
[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

The image url should be the relevant url like "./imageCache/1.png" if your image location is "YourApp/Library/imageCache/1.png".

Hope it helps.